# Show visual progress bar in FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I've seen how I can use FineUploader to show the progress of the upload, but it always shows it in a textual form (like 68%). Is there anyway I can use it in a visual way? For instance, could I set the progress value on the width of a div?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it.

It already automatically adds a width in % to the class defined under the classes properties as 'progressBar'.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything.  The default UI (FineUploader mode) will display a progress bar for you without any additional code.